# Qsort doesn't sort properly array of strings

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm trying to sort array declared as `string *names1 = new string[1];` (the size of an array is growing with adding more items).

I'm putting there strings. The items in array before sorting are:
`novot
svobodovaa
novakj6 3
vondraj1234`

after calling `qsort(names1, size, sizeof (string), compare);`, where compare is implemented like this

```
int compare(const void * a, const void * b) {
return ( *(char*) a - *(char*) b);
}
```

the items in my array are scrambled this way 
`vondraj1234
novakj6
novot
svobodovaa`

Does anybody know, where can be the bug that doesn't allow me to sort the array in alphabetical order?

Comment: Why are you not using `std::vector` since you are coding in C++? And you should not cast to `char*` but to `string*`.

Comment: Make your code to be simpler:
    
    std::vector<std::string> a;
    std::sort(a.begin(), a.end());

Comment: your compare function looks strange. If you want to sort the string alphabetically, you may need to use strcmp function instead?

Comment: I'd love to use vector, but I can't...It's a homework and we've got specified, which includes we can use...And vector is not included :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can **only** use `qsort` with types that can be copied with `memcpy`. `std::string` (and any other type with a non-trivial assignment operator) does not qualify. Instead, use `std::sort`. It knows how to copy objects correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to nitpick at the somewhat poor quality of your question first, bear with me.

```
string *names1 = new string[1];
```

This gives you an array of one (1) string object.

> (the size of an array is growing with adding more items)

False. The size of *your* array might do so, because you hopefully wrote code to this specific end. The size of **an** array does not automatically adjust. (That is what `vector` is for.)

> I'm putting there strings. The items in array before sorting are: `novot svobodovaa novakj6 3 vondraj1234`

In one string? Or as an array of strings? In the latter case, I'd like to see some proof, like thus:

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i )
{
    std::cout << i << ": " << names1[i] << "\n";
}
```

Ideally just before your line:

```
qsort(names1, size, sizeof (string), compare);
```

(I just hope and assume that `size` actually *is* the correct size of `names1`, another thing that my little loop above would prove.)

---

The real reason for your troubles is, however, this line:

```
return ( *(char*) a - *(char*) b);
```

You're casting `string *` (pointer to object) to `char *` (pointer to plain old data), and you are doing it C style (`char*`) instead of C++ style (`static_cast< char * >()`), so your compiler cannot even complain properly.

When you are dereferencing those two pointers, you get the first byte of the two `string` objects, respectively. This is most likely **not** the first character of the contained string, but either a jump table or machine code. Hence the somewhat random result...